# Change row cell background color based on portion of text found in specific cell range

Tags: jquery, datatable

I've looked at some scripts involving changing row background colors based on the entire cell value but I'm looking to run through a sheet and search for an instance of "domaincontrol.com". I have a list of goDaddy domains in a spreadsheet and I am trying to automatically change the background color of the entire row to red IF the instance of domaincontrol.com exists in cells G1-Z partially (note the cell values contain variants like ns12.domaincontrol.com and ns13.domaincontrol.com hence why I'm only looking for the partial string "domaincontrol").

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MainList');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('g1:z');
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var n = i+1;
    var bgColor = (values[i].indexOf('domaincontrol') == -1) ? 'white' : 'red';
    sheet.getRange('a'+n+':z'+n).setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
  }
};
```

This is what I have ultimately come up with but it doesn't seem to be working for me when I run the script.

Added Note: When Logging through `Logger.log(values[i]);` it logs the correct values and displays them from JS array in the log viewer. I'm confused why the terniary isn't operating properly when finding through indexOf. Is there another suitable way to search for the instance of 'domaincontrol' in the cells with the loop in my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll write the answer to my own question here as I have figured out the issue. I was able to search the partial string domaincontrol properly by using the `toString();` function referenced here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString . This allowed me to then search for it properly, for some reason and if anybody could clarify that would be great but it wasn't allowing me to search for the partial instance of domaincontrol inside the array format so parsing it to a string solved this.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('**YourSheetName**');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('**SpreadSheetRange**');
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var n = i+1;
    var row = values[i];
    var rowString = values[i].toString();
    var bgColor = (rowString.indexOf("domaincontrol") == -1) ? "white" : "red";
    //Logger.log(row.indexOf);
    sheet.getRange('a'+n+':z'+n).setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
  }
};
```

I will also note that it seems indexOf IS case sensitive. So when doing something like this I'd run the script for both instances of lowercase and uppercase or run `toLowerCase();` on the string so it captures properly.